# Problem 19 chapter 9 from PMA Rudin

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Show that the system of equations $$\begin{cases}
3x + y - z+u^2=0 \\
x - y + 2z+u=0 \\
2x + 2y - 3z+2u=0
\end{cases}$$ can be solved for $x,y,u$ in terms of $z$; for $x,z,u$ in terms of $y$; for $y,z,u$ in terms of $x$; but not for $x,y,z$ in terms of $u$.

**Proof:** Let $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $$\mathbf{f}(x,y,z,u)=(3x + y - z+u^2, x - y + 2z+u, 2x + 2y - 3z+2u).$$ Also we see that $\mathbf{f}(0,0,0,0)=(0,0,0)$ and $\mathbf{f}'(0,0,0,0)=A$ where $[A]$ has the following form (relative to the standard basis) $$[A]=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & -3 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Our linear operator $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^4,\mathbb{R}^3)$ can be written as: $A(x,y,z,u)=A_1(x,y,u)+A_2(z)$ where $A_1(x,y,u)=A(x,y,0,u)$ and $A_2(z)=A(0,0,z,0)$. And $$[A_1]=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1  & 0 \\
1 & -1  & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Since $\det[A_1]=-12\neq 0$ then $A_1$ is invertible. Then by implicit function theorem exists open neighborhood $W\in \mathbb{R}$ and $U\in \mathbb{R}^4$ of $0$ and $(0,0,0,0)$ respectively. Also to every $z\in W$ exists a unique $(x(z),y(z), u(z))$ such that $$(x(z),y(z), u(z),z)\in U \quad\text{and}\quad \mathbf{f}(x(z),y(z), u(z),z)=0.$$ Hence the system of equations can be solved for $x,y,u$ in terms of $z$. Analogous reasoning can be applied for another cases.

How to show rigorously that above system can not be solved for $x,y,z$ in terms of $u$?

Can anyone give the full answer? I would be very grateful for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the $(a_k,b_k,c_k)$ to mean the 3 vectors of the coefficients before (x,y,z) from the 3 equations.

The system is not solvable because these $3$ vectors are not linearly independent. Multiply the 2nd equation's vector by $-1$ and add it to the 1st one's vector. You get the vector of the 3rd equation.

This means the main determinant is $0$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

See "undetermined system". OK, if you do that operation I mentioned, you get that:

$u^2 - u = 2u$
i.e.
$u=0$ or $u=3$

So:
1) when $u=0$ or $u=3$ the system has infinitely many solutions (because it's practically a system of 2 equations with 3 unknowns, one of the equations just follows from the other 2);
2) when neither $u=0$ nor $u=3$ the system has no solutions (since it leads to a contradiction).

In case 2) it's all clear. In case 1) you cannot solve $x,y,z$ with $u$ because you have to ALSO make one of $x,y,z$ a parameter i.e. you cannot uniquely determine $x,y,z$ as functions of $u$ and $u$ only.

Comment: Nice answer! In case 1) where $u\in \{0,3\}$ we have 2 equations with 3 unknowns and hence one of the $x,y,z$ must be a parameter. But you wrote that "in this case we can not represent $x,y,z$ as function of $u$ and only $u$" Why is this so? I think so: If we can represent $x,y,z$ as function of $u$ and only $u$ then for $u=0$ we would have a unique solution but our solution can be parametrized as $x=\frac{7z}{4}$ and $y=-\frac{z}{4}$. Am I right?

Comment: @RFZ Yes, that's what I meant, z is also a parameter of the solutions, not only u.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Is my proof above where I used implicit function theorem true?

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in your matrix $[A]$. The coefficient $A_{1,3}$ is $-1$ and not $+1$.

Fixing this error, you'll verify that the determinant of the $3 \times 3$ extracted matrix from $[A]$ is equal to $0$. This is why $x,y,z$ cannot be solved in term of $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Solving for $x, y, z$ in terms of $u$ presents us with three linear equations in three unknowns.  From familiar linear algebra, the equations have a unique solution if the determinant of the matrix is nonzero.  The matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1  & -1 \\
1 & -1  & 2 \\
2 & 2 & -3 
\end{bmatrix}$$
It is easy to see that the second and third rows add to the first row. The determinant is therefore zero.

*Edited to add discussion of nonlinear aspect*.  While you seem to have proven, modulo a small error, that the nonlinear equations are solvable in a neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$, their form allows more to be inferred.  Suppose $z$ is the independent variable.  The matrix for $x,y$ obtained from the last two equations is 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
2 & 2  
\end{bmatrix}$$
The determinant is easily seen to be nonzero.  Thus, we can write $x$ and $y$ as linear functions of $u$ and $z$ based on those two equations.  We then substitute those expressions for $x$ and $y$ in the first equation.  It becomes a quadratic equation in $u$ with a coefficient dependent on $z$.  The leading term is $u^2$ since everything else is linear in $u$ and $z$.  Now, all quadratic equations with nonzero leading coefficient have roots, which however may be complex.  As a result, if we allow $u$ to be complex, the nonlinear equations are solvable for *all* $z$, not just in a neighborhood of $z=0$.  It takes some calculation to see what $z$ would allow $u$ to be real.